# OPENROWSET() .xlsx column name in second row

Tags: sql, sql-server, row, xlsx, openrowset

I use `OpenRowset()` to fetch data from a .xlsx file.
However in my file the column name starts on another row.

[image]

I have tried using `[sheet1$A3:B]`but this does not seem to work with `openrowset()`

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
  'Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES
   Database=C:\temp\tmp.xlsx',
   [sheet1$])
```

[image]

How do i say what row i would like have as my column name?

Comment: Try something like `'SELECT * FROM [sheet1$A3:B5]'` instead of only `[sheet1$]`

Comment: Hi, i have tride using [sheet1$A3:B] and if i add (5) it did not do the trick.

"The OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)" does not contain the table "sheet1$A3:B5". The table either does not exist or the current user does not have permissions on that table."

Comment: `[sheet1$A3:B]` is not the same as `'SELECT * FROM [sheet1$A3:B]'` I would recommend trying again.

Comment: Did you look at the BULK option where you can specify FIRSTROW?

Comment: Jacob H: i do not understand what you mean? I have used "SELECT 
 *
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
  'Excel 12.0 Xml;
   Database=C:\temp\tmp.xlsx',
   [sheet1$A3:B5])" but i did not work

Comment: SMM: Bulk option do not work with excel (.xlsx) what i know of?

Comment: @Nils you aren't doing what I am suggesting... good luck though.

Answer (score 0):

```
     `SELECT 
        *
      FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
         'Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES
          Database=C:\temp\tmp.xlsx',
           [sheet1$a3:b])`
```

next to sheet1$ add the first column letter with the row number you wish to start
"a3" and then the letter where you wish to finish in this case "b".
remember it must end with data if you put a letter like "c" where you have no data
it will give you an error

i know its same years late but it may be of use to samebody